# Aligning images below and next to each other

Tags: html, css, image

I've managed to align these 4 images next to each other using `display: inline-block` but I have 2 more images and I want to put them below the 4 other images, I've tried many methods but nothing seems to be working. This is the my CSS and the image of what it looks like now

```
.product1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;          
}

.product2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;         
}

.product3 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.product4 {
    display: inline-block;
}

.product5 {
    width: 230px;

}

.product6 {
    width: 230px;
}
```

html code of images:

```
<div class="product1">
    <div class="watch1">
        <img src="resources/watch1.jpg" alt="watch1" height="230" width="230" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h5>AUDEMARS PIGUET</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <h6>20,700</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product2">
    <div class="watch2">
        <img src="resources/watch2.jpg" alt="watch2" height="230" width="230" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h5>AUDEMARS PIGUET</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <h6>20,700</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product3">
    <div class="watch3">
        <img src="resources/watch3.jpg" alt="watch3" height="230" width="230" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h5>AUDEMARS PIGUET</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <h6>20,700</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product4">
    <div class="watch4">
        <img src="resources/watch4.jpg" alt="watch4" height="230" width="230" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h5>AUDEMARS PIGUET</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <h6>20,700</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product5">
    <div class="watch5">
        <img src="resources/watch5.jpg" alt="watch5" height="230" width="230" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h5>AUDEMARS PIGUET</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <h6>20,700</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product6">
    <div class="watch6">
        <img src="resources/watch6.jpg" alt="watch6" height="230" width="230" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h5>AUDEMARS PIGUET</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <h6>20,700</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screen shot of current state
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnv7F.jpg)

Comment: I think you should try using Flexbox. If you want this to work in older browsers you might need a fallback but flexbox is the way you solve these kind of things with. You can find how to do exactly what you want here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide the html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the images responsive and align them in center using this:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz8adefk/1/)

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23.5%;
    margin: 0 1% 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.container img {
    display: block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div><img src="" alt="Image 1" /></div>
    <div><img src="" alt="Image 2" /></div>
    <div><img src="" alt="Image 3" /></div>
    <div><img src="" alt="Image 4" /></div>
    <div><img src="" alt="Image 5" /></div>
    <div><img src="" alt="Image 6" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello :) I would revise your approach to this mark up. You should create a common DIV for all these .product DIVs and then use width: 25% rule for each of them. So your HTML would look like:

```
<div id="images-container">
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS...

```
#images-container {
    width: 600px; /* put your width according to your mark-up */
}

.product {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

You may also refer to Bootstrap library looking for more up to date solutions at http://www.getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 1):

```
.product1, .product2, .product3 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.product4 {
    float: left;
}

.product5 {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

.product5, .product6 {
    width: 230px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

- wrap the image into a div
- fix the parent width
- fix the image container width

  and do something like this code

```css
.parent{
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  /*or immediatly width: 25%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="image-container"></div>
</div>
```